# sqlsrv_connect() takes 0.3 seconds every time used. it also seems not to use pooling even if it's on

Tags: php, sqlsrv

This is the call:

```
$this->conn = sqlsrv_connect( 'tcp:172.16.4.4\SQLTEST,50493', [
  'Database' => 'Extranet', 
  'UID' => 'extranet_service', 
  'PWD' => 'password', 
  'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8', 
  'ConnectionPooling' => 1, 
  'MultipleActiveResultSets' => 0, 
  'TraceOn' => 0 ]
);
```

This alone takes 0.3 seconds every single time and we have not found any way to make it faster.

Even after turning the ConnectionPooling to 0 it still takes 0.3 seconds, which makes us to believe the connection pooling is not working in the first place?

Is this common behaviour for sqlsrv or are there any ways we can debug this or make it faster?